# Alternating materials on one object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm a beginner using `three.js` and I am trying to have two materials defined on one single object, and alternate between the two using a visibilty flag, but with no success. 
Is there another way, or can this be done?

```
var materials = [
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00,visible:true, shininess: 1 } ),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff0000,visible:false, shininess: 1 } )
];

obj= THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, materials );
scene.add( obj);

scene.traverse(function (node){
    if(node instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        node.visible =!node.visible;
    }
});
```

I will entually aplly this to all objects in the scene that's why I'm using the scene.traverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to apply visibility to the materials, yet you're checking the meshes during your traverse. Remove the `visibility: true/false` from your material definitions, and add the following line:

```
obj= THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, materials );
obj.children[1].visible = false; // add this line
scene.add( obj);
```

This will apply `visibility = false` to the second mesh created by `createMultiMaterialObject`. Your traverse will then correctly flip the visibility of the meshes.

As you get to know `THREE.js` better, you'll want to look into `THREE.MultiMaterial` and geometry groups for applying multiple materials to a single mesh.

Comment: Thank you, it did the trick.
Is it possible to get each material with the     .children[] and change any of the parameters of the material?

Comment: Absolutely! You can access the material of a mesh through its `.material` property. For example, `var materialOfMesh2 = obj.children[1].material`. From there, you can change material properties, such as: `materialOfMesh2.color.setRGB(1, 0, 0);` I highly recommend using breakpoints and browser developer tools (usually through F12) to explore the various properties of the objects, and of course refer back to the THREE.js docs for more info.

Comment: Thank you, it was a big help!

Comment: If you're satisfied with the results of this answer, please mark it as the accepted answer so others can see the question is resolved. Thanks!